# Using MapKit causes Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior

Tags: swift, swiftui, annotations, mapkit

Using Swift5.7, XCode14.0, iOS16.0,

I get very strange error messages and warnings in my XCode console, when trying to make a MapKit example to work.

Here is the log:

```
2022-11-01 17:26:51.756834+0100 myApp[3999:834036] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-11-01 17:26:52.139973+0100 myApp[3999:834036] [PipelineLibrary] Mapping the pipeline data cache failed, errno 22
2022-11-01 17:26:52.192482+0100 myApp[3999:834036] [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""
2022-11-01 17:26:53.884031+0100 myApp[3999:834036] [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.
2022-11-01 17:26:53.900265+0100 myApp[3999:834036] [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.
```

It seems that in SwiftUI, there has been a change in how Published variables in combination with Bindings are handeled.

The core issue, I think, is very nicely described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3a7tuhVpoTQ).

And I assume that Apple has not finished the transition to this new SwiftUI4 behaviour in their own API's themselves.

Or is there any way I can make the `Publishing changes bla bla` warning going away ??

See my entire Code here below:

```
//
//  MyView.swift
//  myApp
//

import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MyView: View {
    
    @State private var showMap = false
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: 37.8879948,
                longitude: 4.1237047
            ),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(
                latitudeDelta: 0.05,
                longitudeDelta: 0.05
            )
        )
    @State private var locations: [Location] = [Location(name: "Test", description: "", latitude: 37.8879948, longitude: 4.1237047)]
    @State private var isLoading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region,
            annotationItems: locations,
            annotationContent: { location in
                MapAnnotation(
                    coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
                ) {
                    VStack {
                        Image("THPin")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                        ZStack {
                            Text(location.name)
                                .padding(5)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .background(.white.opacity(0.5), in: Capsule())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a minimal complete example it's hard to work out where the changes you are trying to make trigger this warning.

Comment: This IS the entire minimal complete example!! Just zoom or pinch the map with your fingers and you see the errors and warnings.... Try the code and you will see... (also the same when updating to XCode14.1, iOS16.1).

Comment: It isn't an MRE because it is missing the `Location` `struct` but I think this is a bug, worthy to report to apple. I don't see where the change is being made.

Answer (score 11):

The same problem! I found that if you replace MapAnnotation with MapMarker the problem disappears. The problem is most likely in the library itself

Comment: Yes!

I was struggling with this thinking that it was an issue with my code... However, it mostly seems that is a bug related to MapAnnotation. Switching back to MapMarker makes the warning disappear. The problem is that I won't be able to have custom markers

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue and was able to fix it using a func returning a binding as follow:

```
private func getRegion() -> Binding<MKCoordinateRegion> {
    return .constant(region)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in iOS 17 on Xcode 15.0.1

Pasting the original code from the poster without any modifications (other than adding the missing `struct Location`) doesn't generate any purple warnings or logs like

> `[SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.`

If you want to give it a try, here is the definition for the missing `Location` struct:

```swift
struct Location: Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        name
    }
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}
```